# ValueError: Expected singleton: res.currency()

Tags: python, odoo14

Estoy trabajando con Odoo 14 y al querer crear una entrada de diario de ventas, utilizando una plantilla creada por mí, me ha surgido el error que incorporo más bajo.

Se trata de un asiento contable para una factura rectificativa de venta intracomunitaria con cuatro apuntes:

- La subcuenta del artículo vendido
- La del IVA intracomunitario repercutido
- La subcuenta del cliente
- La subcuenta del IVA comunitario soportado.

**Todas las cantidades son en la moneda Euro.**

¿Alguien me puede dar una pista para solucionarlo?

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 685, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 361, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 349, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 908, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 533, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1376, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1364, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/api.py", line 399, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/api.py", line 386, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/account_move_template/wizard/account_move_template_run.py", line 184, in generate_move
    move = self.env["account.move"].create(move_vals)
  File "<decorator-gen-273>", line 2, in create
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/api.py", line 347, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/l10n_es_aeat_mod190/models/account_move.py", line 64, in create
    res = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-270>", line 2, in create
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/api.py", line 329, in _model_create_single
    return self.browse().concat(*(create(self, vals) for vals in arg))
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/api.py", line 329, in <genexpr>
    return self.browse().concat(*(create(self, vals) for vals in arg))
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/account_banking_mandate/models/account_move.py", line 35, in create
    getattr(move, onchange_method)()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/l10n_es_aeat_mod190/models/account_move.py", line 58, in _onchange_partner_id
    res = super()._onchange_partner_id()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/account_banking_mandate/models/account_move.py", line 52, in _onchange_partner_id
    res = super()._onchange_partner_id()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/addons/sale/models/account_invoice.py", line 52, in _onchange_partner_id
    return super(AccountMove, self)._onchange_partner_id()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/account_payment_partner/models/account_move.py", line 90, in _onchange_partner_id
    res = super()._onchange_partner_id()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/addons/purchase/models/account_invoice.py", line 83, in _onchange_partner_id
    res = super(AccountMove, self)._onchange_partner_id()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/account_invoice_partner/models/account_move.py", line 19, in _onchange_partner_id
    result = super()._onchange_partner_id()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/account_invoice_fiscal_position_update/models/account_move.py", line 16, in _onchange_partner_id
    res = super()._onchange_partner_id()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/account_global_discount/models/account_move.py", line 209, in _onchange_partner_id
    res = super()._onchange_partner_id()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 487, in _onchange_partner_id
    self._recompute_dynamic_lines()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 1141, in _recompute_dynamic_lines
    invoice._recompute_tax_lines(tax_rep_lines_to_recompute=delta_tax_rep_lines)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/account_invoice_fixed_discount/models/account_move.py", line 19, in _recompute_tax_lines
    res = super(AccountMove, self)._recompute_tax_lines(
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/custom-addons/account_global_discount/models/account_move.py", line 70, in _recompute_tax_lines
    res = super()._recompute_tax_lines(
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 739, in _recompute_tax_lines
    if currency.is_zero(taxes_map_entry['amount']):
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/addons/base/models/res_currency.py", line 178, in is_zero
    self.ensure_one()
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/models.py", line 5024, in ensure_one
    raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 641, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo14/odoo14/odoo/http.py", line 317, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Expected singleton: res.currency()
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no tiene moneda, por alguna razon el campo de moneda le está llegando vacio, revisa si se lo estás pasando o si en algún lugar se pierde.